# Generate and Send CSV file in attachment with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I need to send CSV file to every user with their transaction detail while run cron in symfony

My code is as below to generate csv data and send in email

array of user :

```
$array = array('name','ticket','history','date','flag','created by','transition');
   $f = fopen('php://temp', 'w');
  $line = $array;
  fputcsv($f, $line, ',');
  rewind($f);
 $stream_get_contents = stream_get_contents($f);
$sentmail = $this->sendEmail($stream_get_contents);
if($sentmail){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
fclose($f);
unset($f);


public function sendEmail($csvData){
UserId='1';
    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $getstaffuser = $em->getRepository('AdminBundle:User')->find($UserId);
        if ($getstaffuser) {
            if ($getstaffuser->getEmail()) {
                $objEmailTemplate = $em->getRepository('BviTemplateBundle:Emailtemplate')->findOneBy(array('emailkey' => 'KEYFIND', 'status' => 'Active'));
                if (!$objEmailTemplate) {
                    $output->writeln("\n####### Email template not present #######\n");
                    $logger->info("\n####### Email template not present #######\n");
                    return "NoEmailTemplate";
                }
                $attachment = chunk_split($csvData);
                $multipartSep = '-----' . md5(time()) . '-----';
                $bodydata = $objEmailTemplate->getBody();
                $body = "--$multipartSep\r\n"
                        . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed\r\n"
                        . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n"
                        . "\r\n"
                        . "$bodydata\r\n"
                        . "--$multipartSep\r\n"
                        . "Content-Type: text/csv\r\n"
                        . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
                        . "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"Website-Report-" . date("F-j-Y") . ".csv\"\r\n"
                        . "\r\n"
                        . "$attachment\r\n"
                        . "--$multipartSep--";

                $to = $getstaffuser->getEmail();
                $subject = $objEmailTemplate->getSubject();
                $mail = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                        ->setSubject($subject)
                        ->setFrom($this->getContainer()->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.from_email'))
                        ->setTo($to);

                $mail->setBody($body)
                        ->setContentType('multipart/mixed');

                $issent = $this->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($mail);
                if ($issent) {
                    return 'EmailSent';
                } else {
                    return 'EmailNotSent';
                }
            } else {
                return "NoEmailAddress";
            }
        } else {
            return "NoUser";
        }
}
```

But it is not working , I receive email as only file with noname as filename in attachment ,which is not csv file and not get body content.

Please any body can help me for this.I will appreciate best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try attaching the files to the message directly with Swift as example:

```
$mail = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->setTo($recipient)
            ->setBody($bodyText)
            ->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($absolutePathOfTheAttachedFile));
```

**EDIT:**

Or you can attach by generated data as example:

```
->attach(
         \Swift_Attachment::newInstance($csvData)
           ->setFilename('filename.csv')
           ->setContentType('application/csv') 
        );
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for help,But I need to send that generated csv data as attachement as csv file that generated data is stored in $csvData

Comment: hi @HetalGohel try to check the edit section in the answer if it satisfy your needed. Let me known

Comment: thanks , yes it is working for me as below code ->attach(\Swift_Attachment::newInstance($csvData)
                                ->setFilename('filename.csv')
                                ->setContentType('application/csv'));

Answer (score 0):

Since symfony 3.4 and up use the following code:

```
$message = (new \Swift_Message($subject))
        ->setFrom($from)
        ->setTo($recipient)
        ->setBody($bodyText)
        ->attach(
            (new \Swift_Attachment($csvData))
                ->setFilename('filename.csv')
                ->setContentType('application/csv')
        );
```

Comment: Could you add a short description explaining why OP's solution doesn't work and yours does?

Comment: Cubo78, the answer works, it's just from version 3.4 and up the Swift_Message::newInstance() is changed to (new \Swift_Message($subject)), same for Swift_Attachment.

Comment: I don't mistrust you. Adding a short description could simply help readers to understand the (working) solution.